# How to write this query in Mongoose for MongoDB

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have two document schemas, `User` and `Skill`.

A `User` has a `skills` attribute which has references to `Skill`.

A `Skill` has a `users` attribute which has references to `User`.

I want to be able to query for users who has a certain skill.

```
export async function getUsersWithSkill(skillName: SkillName): Promise<User[]> {
  // NOTE : 'CONNECTION' is the mongoose connection to MongoDB
  const Users = CONNECTION.model<User>('User');

  const users: User[] = await Users
    .find() // does it need a condition in find?
    .populate({
      path: 'skills',
      match: {
        name: { $eq: skillName }
      }
    })
    // or does it need a where clause here?
    // 
    // the following didn't work
    // .where({
    //   skills: { $count : { $gt: 0 }}
    // })
    .exec();

  return users;
}
```

In the above code, the `populate` works as expected, populating only the skills matching the `match` condition in `populate.

The schema stuff is as follows:

```
import { Document, Schema } from 'mongoose';
import { Skill } from './Skill';

export interface User extends Document {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  skills: Skill[];
}

export const UserSchema: Schema<User> = new Schema<User>({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  skills: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Skill'
  }]
});

export interface Skill extends Document {
  name: string;
  users: User[]
}

export const SkillSchema: Schema<Skill> = new Schema<Skill>({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: Object.values(SkillName)
  },
  users: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }]
});

export enum SkillName {
  CSHARP = 'CSHARP',
  FSHARP = 'FSHARP',
  JAVA = 'JAVA',
  JAVASCRIPT = 'JAVASCRIPT',
  TYPESCRIPT = 'TYPESCRIPT',
  PYTHON = 'PYTHON',
  PERL = 'PERL',
  BASH = 'BASH'
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the previous comments, I think the aggregation pipeline is what you need in this case.

Comment: Could you help me out with the syntax?

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/tsdi-IC1WqJ

Comment: @cmgchess thanks very much for that. Do you want to write that comment as an answer so I can accept it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a simple `$lookup` and `$match` in an aggregation pipeline

```js
db.Users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Skills",
      localField: "skills",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "skills"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "skills.name": skillName
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tsdi-IC1WqJ)